# ASP.NET: Rendering flash with jquery load not working

Tags: asp.net, jquery, flash

I have an ASP.NET page where I have a div.I have another ASP.NET page where I have embedded a flash file (.swf) .When I executes the second page.It will come correctly.Now I want to load the out put of the second page to be rendered on the first page.I checked the load method in jQuery. But its not working when in am rendering a flash movie in the second page.When I use a simple h2 tag like This is response from my server , Its working fine.But instead when I try with a flash movie ,Its not coming. I am using jQuery flash pluggin too.

I am ready to switch to some other best method to render a flash movie , if there is some other best method to render flash.

Answer (score 0):

i use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) for embedding SWFs which has a function swfobject.addDomLoadEvent() that provides a means to handle load event...